# Declare properties for storing column position of a line in a file

Tags: c#, variable-declaration

Let's say I have a text file and a line like this:

```
This is an example line within a file.
```

What I need to do is to modify this line based on a prefixed column position, and an input expectedString.

For example:
When i want to modify "example" text from the line above:
I would start from position 11 of that line as an input, and take 7 characters.
It would be something like:

```
TestMethod1()
{
   int posStart = 11;
   int posEnd = 17;
   ModifyLine(line number, posStart, posEnd, expectedString) 
}
```

I may have many similar methods with the only different is the posStart, and posEnd. I want to change it to a shorter version like this:

```
TestMethod1()
{   
    ModifyLine(line number, examplePosStart, examplePosEnd, stringExpected) 
}
```

+examplePosStart, examplePosEnd would be declared somewhere not in the same file.

```
class TextPosition
{
    public constant int example1PosStart = 11;
    public constant int example1PosEnd = 17;
    public constant int example2PosStart = 18;
    public constant int example2PosStart = 25;
}
```

I am wondering are there any other more optimal ways to declare all the posStarts, posEnds in one place like above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array

```
public class TextPosition
{
    public int StartPos { get; set; }
    public int EndPos { get; set; }

    public static readonly TextPosition[] Positions = new[] {
        new TextPosition { StartPos = 11, EndPos = 17 },
        new TextPosition { StartPos = 18, EndPos = 25 }
    } 
}
```